# Restricting scope of Facebook oauth request

Tags: facebook, oauth, scope

I'm using Facebook as a social identity provider, in order to authenticate users of my system. I don't want anything else from Facebook, other than the identity of the user (e.g. the user's Facebook id).

I'm making a passive request to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&**scope=public_profile** - more details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow (see section: invoking the login dialog).

There are several scope options, listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile

My problem is that there doesn't seem to be a scope that limits the access to just the user's Facebook id. This means that when the user first federates, Facebook presents them with a worrying message about all the additional info my app will have access to (see screenshot below). This doesn't work for me, I just need the user's Facebook id - I don't want to ask the user for all this additional stuff. Is it possible to restrict the scope down to just the user's id?

[image: Facebook App Permission Screen]

Comment: No it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask an user to authenticate your app, the minimum that your app **always** asks for is the `public_profile`. You can't get any information fewer than that.

You can read more on the permission here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: Thanks Roemer - good to know. It's a shame, my organization would like to use the social identity, without having to force people to provide additional information they might not want to give and that my organization does not need or want.